# Clickhouse connection refuse

Tags: php, database, clickhouse

I have a problem with connection to clickhouse-server by http over 8123 port. All parameters are default.

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for yandex/clickhouse-server:latest
Include not found: clickhouse_remote_servers
Include not found: clickhouse_compression
2017.11.09 13:05:37.975332 [ 1 ] <Warning> Application: Logging to console
2017.11.09 13:05:37.978638 [ 1 ] <Information> : Starting daemon with revision 54310
2017.11.09 13:05:37.978733 [ 1 ] <Information> Application: starting up
2017.11.09 13:05:37.979947 [ 1 ] <Debug> Application: rlimit on number of file descriptors is 1048576
2017.11.09 13:05:37.979979 [ 1 ] <Debug> Application: Initializing DateLUT.
2017.11.09 13:05:37.980015 [ 1 ] <Trace> Application: Initialized DateLUT with time zone Zulu'.
2017.11.09 13:05:37.980651 [ 1 ] <Debug> Application: Configuration parameter 'interserver_http_host' doesn't exist or exists and empty. Will use 'c9a1a0a75b97' as replica host.
2017.11.09 13:05:37.980783 [ 1 ] <Debug> ConfigReloader: Loading config /etc/clickhouse-server/users.xml'
2017.11.09 13:05:37.983605 [ 1 ] <Warning> ConfigProcessor: Include not found: networks
2017.11.09 13:05:37.983633 [ 1 ] <Warning> ConfigProcessor: Include not found: networks
2017.11.09 13:05:37.984168 [ 1 ] <Information> Application: Loading metadata.
2017.11.09 13:05:37.984738 [ 1 ] <Information> DatabaseOrdinary (default): Total 0 tables.
2017.11.09 13:05:37.984766 [ 1 ] <Information> DatabaseOrdinary (default): Starting up tables.
2017.11.09 13:05:37.984999 [ 1 ] <Debug> Application: Loaded metadata.
2017.11.09 13:05:37.985454 [ 1 ] <Information> Application: Listening http://0.0.0.0:8123
2017.11.09 13:05:37.987644 [ 1 ] <Information> Application: Listening tcp: 0.0.0.0:9000
2017.11.09 13:05:37.987692 [ 1 ] <Information> Application: Listening interserver: 0.0.0.0:9009
2017.11.09 13:05:37.988186 [ 1 ] <Information> Application: Available RAM = 1.95 GiB; physical cores = 4; threads = 4.
2017.11.09 13:05:37.988212 [ 1 ] <Information> Application: Ready for connections.
2017.11.09 13:05:39.980980 [ 2 ] <Debug> ConfigReloader: Loading config /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml'
2017.11.09 13:05:39.985393 [ 2 ] <Warning> ConfigProcessor: Include not found: clickhouse_remote_servers
2017.11.09 13:05:39.985462 [ 2 ] <Warning> ConfigProcessor: Include not found: clickhouse_compression


$ curl 'http://localhost:8123/'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8123: Connection refused
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Did you try binding or using different targets like `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all check if even you clickhouse-server is running properly or not using this command:

`sudo lsof -i :8123`

You should be able to see a similar output:

```
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME

clickhous 8752 root    9u  IPv6  38265      0t0  TCP ip6-localhost:8123 (LISTEN)

clickhous 8752 root   12u  IPv4  38268      0t0  TCP localhost:8123 (LISTEN)
```

Make sure that you have these entries in the config.xml file located at /etc/clickhouse-server

```
<listen_host>::1</listen_host>
<!-- Localhost Binding -->
<listen_host>127.0.0.1</listen_host>
<!-- Remote Access Binding -->
<listen_host>< IP / URL></listen_host>
```

Once you make sure these entries exist, run these commands to restart your server:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ./clickhouse-server --config /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml &
```

Again execute `sudo lsof -i :8123` to see if your clickhouse-server is listening at that port.

Comment: When you set `listen_host` you should set ip/URL of server where ClickHouse deployed, not ip of client server

Answer (score 5):

**UPD**

If you don't want to change a network type, a good solution will be to publish a container's port to the host. It can be done with the `-p HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT` argument. In your case, it would be `-p 8123:8123`. An example:
`docker run -d --name clickhouse-server --ulimit nofile=262144:262144 -p 8123:8123 yandex/clickhouse-server`

**Original answer**

It seems like a docker container is attached to a network you don't have an access to from your host machine. Try to launch an image with `--net=host` flag. Then, run `curl` again.

Additional information about docker network types and its abilities can be found in the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#default-networks)